# How many days does 1 month represent in PHP?

Tags: php

I see there is strange problem in php with month addition and subtraction.

**My questions are:**

does 1 month have an equivalent in days ?

if yes, is this a common standard in all programing languages ?

**A few examples:**

```
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime('2011-03-31 -1 months')); //2011-03-03
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime('2011-03-30 -1 months')); //2011-03-02
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime('2011-03-29 -1 months')); //2011-03-01
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime('2011-03-28 -1 months')); //2011-02-28
```

Comment: @danip, sorry abt that. now i see it

Comment: @danip: the number of days in a month depends on the month.

Comment: Well yeah but you're playing with march and february there, which are special cases. What behaviour did you expect?

Comment: On average, a month is 30.4375 days, assuming 365.25 days per year, accounting for leap years. beyond that, there isn't much consistency.

Comment: I don't expect any behavior. I think my questions are clear.

Comment: @Marc What about leap seconds!? :)

Comment: @Aistina I'm just waiting for a minute with 62 seconds in it.

Comment: @Aistina: one second is about 0.0000000316 of a year, so it's outside the significant figures range. Ask again in about a billion years and we'll argue it out then.

Comment: @Marc Assuming immortality is invented in time, I will!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From your examples, it looks like it's subtracting 1 from the month part, and then correcting for illegal dates. Your second example:

`2011-03-30 - 1 month = 2011-02-30`. This date does not exist, as February 2011 had only 28 days. `30 - 28 = 2`, so it puts it as the 2nd day of the following month.

However, I have not found documentation about this.

Either way, assuming I'm right, the answer to your question is **no**, "1 month" does not have a (constant) equivalent in days, it depends on the input.

Comment: The real question is "How does this change if you use months from around June and July? Does it still use 28 days as its diff value? For example, if we are correct in assuming the value is the number of days in the month before the date you're subtracting from, that would make April 1st's value 31 days, which would put it at March 1st. This means that one month before the day before april first is later in time than one month before april first, which is a logical inconsistency, to say the least.

Comment: I read that `strtotime` behaves exactly as you described. But I seem not to be able to recall where.

Comment: @Oswald This behavior is noted in the documentation comments. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#98834

Comment: @Oswald "the month" being the one being subtracted from? Or the month before the one being subtracted from?

Answer (score 3):

[The way `strtotime` parses date information](http://us.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php) is going to be very valuable here.

What you *seem* to want is the first day of the previous month, right?

Well, you can *chain together* many of these relative commands.  For example, from the PHP interactive shell:

```
php > $d = date_create('2011-03-28 first day -1 month'); if($d) echo $d->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); else echo "Failed.";
2011-02-01 00:00:00
php > $d = date_create('2011-03-29 first day -1 month'); if($d) echo $d->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); else echo "Failed.";
2011-02-01 00:00:00
php > $d = date_create('2011-03-30 first day -1 month'); if($d) echo $d->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); else echo "Failed.";
2011-02-01 00:00:00
php > $d = date_create('2011-03-31 first day -1 month'); if($d) echo $d->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); else echo "Failed.";
2011-02-01 00:00:00
php > $d = date_create('2011-04-01 first day -1 month'); if($d) echo $d->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); else echo "Failed.";
2011-03-01 00:00:00
```

`first day` asks for the first day of the current month.  Asking for `-1 month` goes to the previous month, on the same day.  Because we've already rewound to the first day of the month, this will always work as expected.

Comment: Saved me from typing my answer in. Subtracting or adding months is dangerous to do. See Example #3 in http://us.php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php. If you always want the first/last day of the month, using this "first/last day" approach is the best.