# PHP date() and strtotime() return wrong months on 31st

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I'm using `date()`and `strtotime()` functions to display the next 3 months in a dropdown list.

PHP Code:

```
   echo date("m/Y",strtotime("+0 months")); 
   echo date("m/Y",strtotime("+1 months"));
   echo date("m/Y",strtotime("+2 months"));
```

However, if the script is running when the server date is on 30th or 31st, the next month, which is Feburary, will be displayed as March instead. 
i.e. the script above is supposed to return

```
01/2012
02/2012
03/2012
```

But, instead of that, it actually displays

```
01/2012
03/2012
03/2012
```

that is because Feburary doesn't have 30th or 31st, so the script translates "31/02" into "01/03".

I have read the `strtotime()` page on php.net, this problem has been raised, but there has not been any useful solutions. So can anyone please help me to find a simple way to solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [strtotime returns incorrect timestamp for '-1 month'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481949/strtotime-returns-incorrect-timestamp-for-1-month) and [PHP Strtotime -1month -2month](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211824/php-strtotime-1month-2month) and [How many days does 1 month represent in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464221/how-many-days-does-1-month-represent-in-php) and [strtotime 'next month' not acting as expected (today that is)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182925/strtotime-next-month-not-acting-as-expected-today-that-is)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As mentioned within the documentation, you should pass the date for the first day of the current month as the second parameter to the `strtotime()` function:

```
$base = strtotime(date('Y-m',time()) . '-01 00:00:01');
echo date('m/Y',strtotime('+0 month', $base));
echo date('m/Y',strtotime('+1 month', $base));
echo date('m/Y',strtotime('+2 month', $base));
```

See that it works: http://ideone.com/eXis9

> 01/2012
>
> 02/2012
>
> 03/2012

Comment: Considering `$base = strtotime('2016-12-31' . '-01 00:00:01');` the solution sill prints February 2 times for `+2 month` and `+3 month`

Answer (score 12):

Try using "first day of" in your strtotime, like this:

```
strtotime("first day of +1 month");
```

This will fix dates ( in the event today was Jan 30th ) such as 02-30 (Yields march 2nd) by converting it to 02-01 (Feb 1st) which then gives you the correct month. It's a little cleaner than other methods, and easier to remember.

Comment: Very elegant solution.

Comment: Doesn't work with `FIRST DAY OF -2 MONTHS` on the 31st. `base` is important

Comment: *Shrugg* - Today on 2018-05-31, `echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('FIRST DAY OF -2 MONTH'));` yields -> `2018-03-01`. 5-2 = 3. Seems to work, what example did you have that did not?

Answer (score 5):

```
echo date('m/Y', strtotime(date('Y-m') . '-01 +2 months'));
```

Just hard-code it to be the first of the month.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use strtotime() for getting offset date by month(s). It works properly only in PHP 5.3+.
The best way to solve such problem is using [mktime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php).
Below is a sample code:

```
function getOffsetByMonths($nMonths, $nNow = 0) {
    if ($nNow)
        return mktime(0, 0, 0, date('n', $nNow)+ $nMonths, 1, date('Y', $nNow));
    else
        return mktime(0, 0, 0, date('n')+ $nMonths);
}
$nNow = mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 31, 2013);
echo "Now: ". date("Y-m-d", $nNow).
"<br>(Now - 1 month): ". date("Y-m", getOffsetByMonths(-1, $nNow)). "-xx".
"<br>(Now - 2 month): ". date("Y-m", getOffsetByMonths(-2, $nNow)). "-xx".
"<br>(Now - 3 month): ". date("Y-m", getOffsetByMonths(-3, $nNow)). "-xx";
```