# What happening to php date function

Tags: php, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP date() and strtotime() return wrong months on 31st](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058523/php-date-and-strtotime-return-wrong-months-on-31st)

I have this code and it outputs something strange i think. So, what i am doing wrong here.

```
<?php 
$sP1 = date('m Y');
$sP2 = date('m Y', strtotime('+01 month'));
$sP3 = date('m Y', strtotime('+02 month'));
$sP4 = date('m Y', strtotime('+03 month'));
echo $sP1.'<br>';
echo $sP2.'<br>';
echo $sP3.'<br>';
echo $sP4.'<br>';
?>
```

and this outputs

```
05 2012
07 2012
07 2012
08 2012
```

i think the second one should be

```
06 2012
```

Anybody know any solution?

Comment: See the accepted answer on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058523/php-date-and-strtotime-return-wrong-months-on-31st

Answer (score 2):

Today is the 31st    next month only has 30 days so it would be 7/12 in 1 month from today

```
assuming that today is May 31 2012

date('m Y') == 05 2012
date('m Y', strtotime('+1 month')) == 07 2012 because june has 30 days
date('m Y', strtotime('+2 month')) == 07 2012
date('m Y', strtotime('+3 month')) == 08 2012
date('m Y', strtotime('+4 month')) == 10 2012
```

I would take today's date and find the first day of the month then add a month to that if you are doing something that needs to get each month

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, it is because today is the 31st and +1 month equals June-31 which changes to Jul-1. If you include the day in the date string, you can see exactly this.

```
<?php 
$sP1 = date('m-d-Y');
$sP2 = date('m-d-Y', strtotime('+01 month'));
$sP3 = date('m-d-Y', strtotime('+02 month'));
$sP4 = date('m-d-Y', strtotime('+03 month'));
echo $sP1."\n";
echo $sP2."\n";
echo $sP3."\n";
echo $sP4."\n";
/* Outputs:
    05-31-2012
    07-01-2012
    07-31-2012
    08-31-2012
*/
?>
```

strtotime though can take the start date as part of the string so as King suggested, calculate the +N months from the first. So a string like `May-1-2012 +01 month` such as:

```
<?php
$sP1 = date('m Y');
$sP2 = date('m Y', strtotime(date('M-1-Y').' +01 month'));
$sP3 = date('m Y', strtotime(date('M-1-Y').' +02 month'));
$sP4 = date('m Y', strtotime(date('M-1-Y').' +03 month'));
echo $sP1."\n";
echo $sP2."\n";
echo $sP3."\n";
echo $sP4."\n";
/* Outputs:
    05 2012
    06 2012
    07 2012
    08 2012
*/
?>
```

http://codepad.org/auYLHvDI

Answer (score 1):

It is working as intended.  In a nutshell, it is because what is "one month" from May 31?  June 30?  August 1?

My suggestion is that if you need sequential months, calculate the offset from the start of the current month, not the current day.  Or compose the date that you're looking for manually using the month, day, and year parts broken up.

Comment: What did you do with poor July? :(