# PHP - Fetch Previous Month from Current Month

Tags: php, date, datetime

I need to fetch previous month from the current month passed. Tried below code and it does work for the month having 30 days but does not work for specific months having 31 days viz. `March, May, July, October and December`

Note: The question may sound repeated, but please read it completely till the end. You can check the same issue by changing the system and testing below code against it. I need the previous month output in format `Jul`

For Date: `30-Jul` output is

`Previous Month-Jun
Current Month-Jul`

For Date: `31-Jul` output is

`Previous Month-Jul
Current Month-Jul`

`$prev_month = date('M', strtotime("last month"));
echo 'Previous Month--'.$prev_month;
echo 'Current Month--'.date('M');`

Also tried `echo date('M', strtotime("-1 Months"));` but it outputs the same as above.

If current month is `(August)` with `31` days and so previous month is `(July)` with `31` days then it works and shows correct Previous Month i.e. `July`, but it does not work if current month has `31` days and previous month has `30` or lesser days.

How should I go about it to fetch correct previous month on the basis of current month ?

Comment: Use "m" instead of "M" for month - echo date('m', strtotime("-1 Months"));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply try as

```
echo "Previous Month".date('M',strtotime('first day of last month'));
```

and for specific date you can simply use

```
echo date('M',strtotime('first day of last month',strtotime('30-Jun')));//May
```

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy then change the 'F' to 'M' - otherwise, I like this one.

Comment: @Wizzard Ohh.. yeah that's typo. Thanks for the correction

Comment: @Uchiha why the code `date('M', strtotime("last month"));` was not working and date('M', strtotime("first day of last month")); works ?

Comment: @Uchiha, my code works too but as I said, not in case with months having 31 days like `Jul-Aug`. Your code works for this use case as well. So I just need to know what technically I did wrong.. :)

Comment: Its `(UTC+05:30) Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi`

Answer (score 0):

You should pass in the date from the start of the month.

```
$startDate = date('Y-m-1');
$prevMonth = date('M', strtotime("last month", strtotime($startDate)));
```

see
[PHP date() and strtotime() return wrong months on 31st](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058523/php-date-and-strtotime-return-wrong-months-on-31st)