# Given date + 2 months working wrong for december 30,31

Tags: php, date

I want to get first date of +2 months of given date,Iam using below function to get this .

```
$date = '2015-12-31';
echo $date = date('1-m-Y', strtotime('+2 month', strtotime($date)));
```

This was working fine.But for december 30,31 this is not giving result as expected.for date `2015-12-30` it gives result `'1-03-2016'`.I know because of february having 29 days this gives this result.But expected result is `'01-02-2016'`. This can be solved by writing new function.But i want to go with built in functions.Please Help.

Comment: 01-02-2016 (Feb 1) is just over +1 month from 2015-12-30, ... and not anywhere close to +2 months.  Why is 01-02-2016 your expected result?

Comment: May be try `+60 days`

Comment: @BareNakedCoder I want 1st date of +2 month from month of given date.

Comment: Misread the question, working on the actual problem now

Comment: Not misread.  OP has edited question to say he wants 1st day of month containing $date + 2 months.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP date() and strtotime() return wrong months on 31st](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058523/php-date-and-strtotime-return-wrong-months-on-31st)

Comment: Your logic on this problem is wrong, why are you specifying the first `$date` at all?  There should be no need to calculate it from the 31st if what you want is two months from the 1st.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coming to your way, convert your date to 1st of your desired month and then calculate. Like this:

```
<?php
$date = '2015-12-31';
$date = date('1-m-Y', strtotime($date));
echo $date = date('1-m-Y', strtotime('+2 months',strtotime($date)));
```

You get:

> 1-02-2016

---

**Instead**, you can use `first day of +2 months`:

```
echo $date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime('first day of +2 months',strtotime($date)));
```

Will output (as you desire):

> 01-02-2016

Answer (score 1):

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first day of +2 month', strtotime($date)));
```

`first day of` maps 2015-12-30 to 2015-12-01 then `+2 month` maps it to 2016-02-01.  By mapping to the 1st day of month of your starting date BEFORE adding +2 months, you don't have to to worry about short months.