# Adding month in php?

Tags: php

**month adding problem**

```
<?php 

$showMonthsQty = 3;
for($i = (1-$showMonthsQty); $i <= 0; $i++) 
{
    echo $date = date("Y-m-1", strtotime(" +$i months"));

}
?>
```

when it run's im not geting the desired answer.

**OUTPUT**

```
2018-03-1 
2018-05-1  <----------error
2018-05-1
```

but i needed output is :

```
2018-03-1    
2018-04-1 
2018-05-1
```

how can i get this ?pls help!... tnx in advance...:)

Comment: Please take a [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please give more detailed description.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP date() and strtotime() return wrong months on 31st](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058523/php-date-and-strtotime-return-wrong-months-on-31st)

Comment: tnx for the comment

Comment: Please use correct upper case letters!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/fr/class.datetime.php) and [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/fr/class.dateinterval.php).

```
$showMonthsQty = 3;
for($i = $showMonthsQty-1; $i >= 0; $i--) 
{
    $date = new \DateTime(date("Y-m-1")); // First day of the current month
    $date->sub(new \DateInterval(sprintf('P%sM', $i))); // Substract $i month (P%dM)

    echo $date->format('Y-m-d')."<br />";
}
```

**Output:**

```
2018-03-01
2018-04-01
2018-05-01
```

Is it what you're looking for ?