# get last day of the next month in php?

Tags: php, date

I have a php code as shown below in which I am trying to retrieve the last day of next month.

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('America/Toronto');

echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');

$next_month_last_day  = date('t', strtotime('next month'));  // last day of the next month

print_r("\n");

print_r($next_month_last_day);   // Line A

?>
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what mistake I have done in the php code above because the code at **Line A** prints 31. It should be printing 30 because the last 
day of next month **(April)** is 30.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686724/how-to-find-the-last-day-of-the-month-from-date

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058523/php-date-and-strtotime-return-wrong-months-on-31st

Comment: @mech Whats wrong I am doing in the code above ?

Comment: @flash See my link: "PHP date() and strtotime() return wrong months on 31st"

Answer (score 3):

Just use

```
date('d', strtotime('last day of +1 month'));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `last day of next month`

```
$date = new \DateTime('last day of next month');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to go about it is to get the first day of the next month, then use `t` to format it to the number of days of that month.

```
echo date("t", strtotime("first day of next month")); // 2021-04-30  10:27:35
```

Answer (score -1):

I had to manually overwrite today's day so DateTime wouldn't skip a month. But it doesn't matter since you only want to know what the next month is.

```
$dateTime = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone("America/Toronto"));
$dateTime->setDate($dateTime->format('Y'), $dateTime->format('m'), 01);

$nextMonth = $dateTime->modify('+1 month');

echo cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $nextMonth->format('m'), $nextMonth->format('Y'));
```

Answer (score -1):

**Try This**

```
$lastDay = date('t',strtotime('next month'));

 

print_r($lastDay);
```