# Last day of next month in PHP or Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, php-carbon

When I try to get the last day of next month by PHP or Laravel carbon, everything is ok, but when I try to get the last day of next month from a specific date, 2023-01-31, by

```
date('Y-m-01', strtotime('next month', strtotime('2023-01-31')));
```

OR

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:m:00:000', '2023-01-31')->addMonth()->format('Y-m-t H:m:00:000');
```

That time output results are given on 2023-03-31, but the last day of next month is 2023-02-28. So how can I solve it? It's not working correctly.

```
$instituter = Institute::where('code', $instInfo->institute_code)->first();
            // $institute = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:m:00:000', $institute->institute_expire)->addMonth()->format('Y-m-d H:m:00:000');
            // $expire = $instituter->institute_expire;
            // $inst = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:00.000', $instituter->institute_expire)->addMonths(6)->startOfMonth()->format('Y-m-d');
            $inst = date('Y-m-01', strtotime('next month', strtotime($instituter->institute_expire)));
            // $inst = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:00.000', $instituter->institute_expire)->addMonths(6)->startOfMonth();
            // $institute = Carbon::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $instituter->institute_expire)->addMonth();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [get last day of the next month in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60954625/get-last-day-of-the-next-month-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

From Laravel 5.5 you can use now() function to get the current date and time and you can get the last date of next month using :

```
now()->addMonth()->endOfMonth();
```

if you want to format to Y-m-d

```
now()->addMonth()->endOfMonth()->format('Y-m-d');
```

or if you want to get only date change format to $now->format('d');

if you are using laravel version less than 5.5 using the above functions as

```
\Carbon\Carbon::now()->addMonth()->endOfMonth();
```

Answer (score 1):

A date is given as a string.

```
$strDate = '2023-01-15';
```

Based on this date, a date object is to be created for the last day of the following month. With DateTime this can be done in one line.

```
$lastDdayOfNextMonth = date_create('last day of next month '.$strDate);
```

Carbon is an extension of DateTime. Therefore this also works:

```
$lastDdayOfNextMonth = Carbon::create('last day of next month '.$strDate);

echo $lastDdayOfNextMonth->format('c');
//2023-02-28T00:00:00+01:00
```

If the date already exists as an object, it becomes even easier.

```
$dt = new DateTime('2023-01-15');

$lastDdayOfNextMonth = $dt->modify('last day of next month');
```

This works exactly the same with carbon again.

```
$dt = new Carbon('2023-01-15');

$lastDdayOfNextMonth = $dt->modify('last day of next month');
```

Beware of solutions with addMonth() with Carbon or just 'next Month' for DateTime. Older versions also return incorrect results for the date "2023-01-31" as with the question. Carbon has a special method for adding months 'without overflow': [addMonthsNoOverflow()](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-addsub)

```
$endOfNextMonth = Carbon::create('2023-01-31')
  ->addMonthsNoOverflow(1)
  ->endOfMonth()
;

echo $endOfNextMonth;  //2023-02-28 23:59:59
```

Answer (score 0):

strtotime will do this ...

e.g.

`echo date('c', strtotime('last day of next month'));`

gives e.g. 2023-02-28T19:53:34+00:00, when today is 2023/01/21.

Alternatively -

`ècho (new DateTime('last day of next month'))->format('c')`

will also work

Answer (score -1):

Here is the updated answer after realise of the actual requirement.

```
// Get the today date
$todayDate = Carbon::now();

// Calculate the first day of the next month
$firstDayOfNextMonth = $todayDate->copy()->addMonth()->startOfMonth();

// Calculate the last day of the next month
$lastDayOfNextMonth = $firstDayOfNextMonth->copy()->endOfMonth();

// Formatted date
$formattedLastDay = $lastDayOfNextMonth->format('Y-m-d');
```